# pcap_next call fills in pcap_pkthdr with len equal to zero

Tags: c++, c, libpcap

I'm using **libpcap** of version **1.1.1** built as a static library(**libpcap.a**). When I try to execute a following block of code on RHEL 6 64 bit(The executable module itself is built as 32-bit ELF image) I get segmentation fault:

```
const unsigned char* packet;
pcap_pkthdr pcap_header = {0};
unsigned short ether_type = 0;

while ( ether_type != ntohs( 0x800 ) )
{
    packet = pcap_next ( m_pcap_handle, &pcap_header );
    if (packet != NULL)
    {
        memcpy ( &ether_type, &( packet[ 12 ] ), 2 );
    }
    else
    {
    /*Sleep call goes here*/
    }
}

if ( raw_buff ->data_len >= pcap_header.caplen )
{
    memcpy ( raw_buff->data, &(packet[14]), pcap_header.len -14 );
    raw_buff->data_len = pcap_header.len -14;
    raw_buff->timestamp = pcap_header.ts; 
}
```

A bit of investigation revealed **pcap_header.len** field is equal to zero upon **pcap_next** return. In fact **caplen** field seems to reflect packet size correсtly. If I try to dump a packet memory from **packet** address - data seems to be valid. As of **len** field equal to zero I know it's invalid. It supposed to be at least as of **caplen** magnitude. Is it a bug? What steps shall I take to get this fixed?

GDB shows **pcap_header** contents as:

(gdb) p pcap_header

$1 = {ts = {tv_sec = 5242946, tv_usec = 1361456997}, caplen = 66, len = 0}

Maybe I can have some workaround applied? I don't want to upgrade **libpcap** version.

Comment: Perhaps the rest of your code is messing up the header data. Try running your app under valgrind to see if there is something else wrong with memory management.

Comment: Note that caplen is the length you need to care about. It says how much data there is in the captured packet. The len member is the original length of the packet on the wire, but you may not have captured all of that (mostly dependent on the snaplen setting) If len is < caplen, it's a bug.

Comment: I have already read about similar case and I know len is supposed to be greather or equal to caplen but not less. That's the point - I have no idea what to do with this. Some stable workaround would be applicable.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: Is it ok to skip **len** checking and check only **caplen** field? I.e. the actual len of the packet can be taken from the packet itself. I can cast **packet** buffer to **ip_hdr** and you know what I'm going to perform next. Is it applicable? Are there any don'ts regarding this?

Comment: @AlexanderChernyaev Yes it's ok to not care the len member, as it is caplen and not len that tells you the length of the data you have. Ofcourse, you'll want to check that you have enough data for an IP header, and enough data as you start digging into the other layers.

Comment: Unfortunatelly neither upgrading **libpcap** nor this workaround helped this much. I'm still getting **len**=0 as well as the packets I receive appear to be broken. Ethertype is equal to 0x72a7. I don't know about any network protocol of this type number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I googled for "https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=557728" defect description and it seems it is still relevant nowadays. The problem went away when I linked my application to a shared library version of **libpcap** instead of having it linked with a static one. Then a system gets my app linked to a **libpcap** at runtime which is being shipped with RHEL.

Sincerely yours, Alexander Chernyaev.

Answer (score 1):

Kernels prior to the 2.6.27 kernel do not support running 32-bit binaries using libpcap 1.0 or later on a 64-bit kernel.

libpcap 1.0 and later use the "memory-mapped" capture mechanism on Linux kernels that have it available, and the first version of that mechanism did not ensure that the data structures shared between the kernel and code using the "memory-mapped" capture mechanism were laid out in memory the same way in 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

2.6 kernels prior to the 2.6.27 kernel have only the first version of that mechanism.  The 2.6.27 kernel has the second version of that mechanism, which *does* ensure that the data structures are laid out in memory the same way in 32-bit and 64-bit mode, so that 32-bit user-mode code works the same atop 32-bit and 64-bit kernels.

Comment: But in fact I use 2.6.32-279.e16.x86_64. It's more recent than 2.6.27 is. So I believe it should not be a problem. Any other ideas?